# no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: postgresql

When trying to connect to my AWS RDS database from my project I get this error:

```
error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xx.xx.xx.xx", user "myUser", database "myDatabase", no encryption
```

postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

pg_hba.conf:

```
local all         all              scram-sha-256
host  all         all 127.0.0.1/32 scram-sha-256
host  all         all ::1/128      scram-sha-256
local replication all              scram-sha-256
host  replication all 127.0.0.1/32 scram-sha-256
host  replication all ::1/128      scram-sha-256
```

My credentials work fine for pgadmin4 and for psql, and I'm able to connect to a different AWS RDS database from this project fine. What am I missing and/or what should I try to allow me to connect to my db.

Comment: "what should I try" -- add a `pg_hba.conf` entry, maybe?

Comment: @mustaccio yeah ive tried that, I added a entry as per the error message, and restarted the  postgresql service, made no difference

Comment: Amazon RDS, as a cloud service, does not expose the `pg_hba.conf` file. I would surmise that your app tries to connect to a server that is not an RDS instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that my ssl certificate was the issue, as I was not properly providing it. Presumably that was why the error message mentioned `no encryption`, as all the entries in `pg_hba.conf` expected `scram-sha-256` but received nothing. To expand it seems like the above error message is a generic message to prevent random people trying to access your endpoint from gaining too much insight.